# Rails Tutorial Chapter 11 regarding update_attribute vs update_attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

In [Chapter 11 of the Rails tutorial book](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/account_activation#cha-11_footnote-ref-8) (sect. 11.3.2), author says in the [footnote(8)](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/account_activation#cha-11_footnote-8) :

> Here we use two calls to update_attribute rather than a single call to updated_attributes because (per Section 6.1.5) the latter would run the validations. Lacking in this case the user password, these validations would fail.

hence using the code in **~/app/controllers/account_activations_controller.rb**:

```
class AccountActivationsController < ApplicationController

  def edit
    user = User.find_by(email: params[:email])
    if # user and link is valid
      user.update_attribute(:activated,    true)
      user.update_attribute(:activated_at, Time.zone.now)          
      # Handle successful activation
    else
      # Handle unsuccessful activation
    end
  end
end
```

updates the `activated` and `activated_at` attributes of the `user` object.

but if I replaced

```
user.update_attribute(:activated,    true)
user.update_attribute(:activated_at, Time.zone.now)
```

to

```
user.update_attributes(activated: true, activated_at: Time.zone.now)
```

the activation still succeeds and the database is also updated even when 'lacking the user password'.

Why is this so? I've done testing on the rails console and only found that `update_attributes` will only fail to update when the supplied hashes are invalid due to validations in the model file. But for updating attributes that are not being validated by the model file, the update still happens.

I'm just confused because he could have used `update_attributes` instead of two lines since they both work.

**EDIT:** Here's my User model as well, as you can see it has the proper validations for password.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  .
  .
  has_secure_password
  validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }, allow_nil: true
  .
end
```

Comment: Are you sure you did not miss a step which adds length and presence validations to the password?

Comment: It could also be that the validations are added in a later step. It does not make sense that Hartl would omit them since he is very thorough.

Comment: @max I've added the User model for reference. The validations are in place. I'm now in chapter 13, everything should be in place for the basic attributes, the activation still works with either update_attribute or update_attributes